# an iframe changing a picture in a div in the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, parent

I'm an absolute novice when it comes to jQuery and JavaScript, but what I am attempting to do is have an iframe that contains thumbnail images which, when clicked, will change a picture in a div on my parent page.

Answer (score 0):

use the `postMessage` function that allows the communication between a iframe and its container

That will work only on same origin iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the iframe is the same domain as the parent page, you can use JavaScript's `parent` object to access the parent of the iframe's DOM and global JavaScript.

So within the iframe, your code might look something like this:

```
$("img").on("click", function() {
 parent.document.getElementById("myPictureID").style.backgroundImage = "some-image.jpg";
});
```

You'd have to modify the image to take it from the thumbnail somehow, maybe as a data-attribute. `<img class="thumbnail" data-image="someBiggerImage.jpg" />`.

Comment: thanks, this worked exactly as I needed, im still a bit confused by jquery but I was able to get this working. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution.

// Assume that img in the iFrame And you want to change the picture of the Main page.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#img").on("click", function() {
     window.parent.$("#myPictureID").css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat");
    });
  });
```

// Assume that img in the iFrame And you want to change the picture in the iframe itself.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#img").on("click", function() {
   $("#myPictureID").css("background", "url(/images/r-srchbg_white.png) no-repeat");
    });
  });
```